# Fatal error: Call to a member function in product.php

Tags: php, opencart

I am new to opencart, so please help me.
I am using opencart version 1.5.6, now whenever I edit and delete the product it shows me

> Fatal error: Call to a member function productUpdateListen() on a non-object in /home/crazepur/public_html/admin/controller/catalog/product.php on line 78 
>   and 
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function deleteProduct() on a non-object in /home/crazepur/public_html/admin/controller/catalog/product.php on line 133 respectively.

Although it edit and delete the product.
Please help me how to fix it.

Code in Line 78 `$this->openbay->productUpdateListen($this->request->get['product_id'], $this->request->post);`

And code in line 133 `$this->openbay->deleteProduct($product_id);`

Comment: `var_dump($this->openbay);`

Comment: NULL 
Fatal error: Call to a member function productUpdateListen() on a non-object in /home/crazepur/public_html/admin/controller/catalog/product.php on line 78

Comment: Code is
"$this->load->model('catalog/product');
 var_dump($this->openbay);
     if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validateForm())
      { 
   $this->model_catalog_product->editProduct($this->request->get['product_id'], $this->request->post);
            
           (var_dump($this->openbay->productUpdateListen($this->request->get['product_id'], $this->request->post)));
   
   ($this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success'));
   
   $url = '';

Answer (score 1):

This means `$this->openbay` is not an object which contains function `productUpdateListen()` & `deleteProduct()`, probably it's NULL or false in some cases (nothing found) due to it's not accessible. Out of scope.

Try

```
var_dump($this->openbay);
```

Check the O/P

Answer (score 0):

it's simple and the error-message says it all: your `$this->openbay` doesn't have those methods (`productUpdateListen()` and `deleteProduct()`) - most likely it isn't an object at all.

please debug your code since it's impossible to say what's going wrong wich so little information. to start, do a `var_dump($this->openbay);` right before the function-calls and check the output.

Comment: NULL 
Fatal error: Call to a member function productUpdateListen() on a non-object in /home/crazepur/public_html/admin/controller/catalog/product.php on line 78

Comment: Code is
"$this->load->model('catalog/product');
 var_dump($this->openbay);
     if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validateForm())
      { 
   $this->model_catalog_product->editProduct($this->request->get['product_id'], $this->request->post);
            
           (var_dump($this->openbay->productUpdateListen($this->request->get['product_id'], $this->request->post)));
   
   ($this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success'));
   
   $url = '';"

Comment: i won't read a bunch of messy code in a comment. edit your question and insert your _properly formatted_ code there. anyway, you can already see `$this->openbay` is `NULL` - and `NULL` doesn't have any methods.